# Dynamics 365 create subuser under a user account

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

Is there any possibility to create sub-users under a user account using one license, but taking into account they need to have full access to the main functionalities of the CRM.

Answer (score 2):

No. Even by sharing a user between multiple people you would likely be breaching your licence terms.

Without understanding why you would want to do this, if the reason is cost, I would suggest investigating Power Apps and Team Member licences. They are a cheap way to access Dynamics data, although can be restrictive.